# Purpose of pyVim within pyVmomi

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I'm trying to get used to Python and VMware vSphere API Python Bindings (pyVmomi). I try to understand the purpose of each component. What's the purpose of pyVim within pyVmomi? From what I understand, pyVim is used for connection handling (creation, deletion...) to the Virtualization Management Object Management Infrastructure (VMOMI). Is this correct?

Thank you & best regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. Also as of recently some new Task handling functionality has been added to pyVim as well. The new task stuff abstract out making property collectors to monitor task progress and such. The connection classes provided allow various authentication methods supported by vSphere such as basic auth, SSPI, and a few others. It also handles disconnecting and cleaning up connections once closed. The VMOMI classes from pyVmomi are the objects inside vSphere like HostSystem, VirtualMachines, Network, etc.

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Comment: @michael do you know what's the token required for SSPI as auth method? How can I get a token?